# RecyclerView crops bottom data

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

i have a constraintlayout with a recyclerview. some items of my list not appears because the recyclerview is croping. When i see the constraint bottom of recyclerview to bottom of my parent everything works fine in the bottom, but i have  other problem in the top. The recycler view going to the back of my cardview, cuting some itens of top.

is that my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/shadow"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtExpenseValue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/expense_category"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_folder"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:layout_width="51dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_add_newdesign"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="R$ 15.000,00"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/myCardView" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/shadow"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtTotalPrice" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

im tried to use margin to correct, but not works.
[image: That is my layout!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constrain the bottom of the `RecyclerView` to the bottom of the parent and set its `android:layout_height` to `0dp` to match constraints instead of `match_parent`. It's not recommended to use `match_parent` for `Views` contained in a `ConstraintLayout` as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout):

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".